# SQL Server Express 2016: Is it possible to run queries, using as a source a remote database (i.e. on another sql server)?

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to use SQL Server Express 2016 for my work. My problem is that it's only an express version with size limitations, and our databases are enormous. The full databases are located on SQL Server Enterprise, which is in fact the official master sql server in our company. So I was wondering if it would be possible to somehow connect sql server express to the master sql server, and remotely run queries using the master database as a source, without having it created on my server.
Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: There's a difference between having a SQL Server instance, and running SQL Server Management Studio. As far as I know, you should be able to connect to another database, regardless of the version of SSMS you have installed. That said, if that doesn't work, I believe SQL Server Developer Edition is free for 2016, so you could simply install that instead (which is essentially Enterprise edition that's not licensed to run in production).

Comment: As a beginner I'm still confusing things, it's SQL Server Management Studio. I think the result of these queries will be used in production, so the Developer version is not an option. Would you be so kind to advise me how to connect to another database? I read a lot in the internet, but became even more confused :( Thank you!

Comment: So you've got the actual database instance you're trying to connect to, which is subject to all the licensing issues and size restrictions youre' talking about. Then you've got Management Studio which is just a visual studio shell for interacting with those databases. Frequently they're insatlled together, but you can access, say, a 2014 instance from SSMS 2008 and so forth. Since Microsoft doesn't really care what you use to access the database, just the databse installation itself, I think whatever SSMS version came with express should work just fine

Comment: Do I understand correctly -  SSMS (which I installed together with sql server express and has nothing to do with the official sql server), can be used to access the master database, which is created in the official sql server enterprise?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes.

Comment: And if that turns out not to be the case, you can download SSMS as a standalone, or install something like SQL Server Developer Edition. The link for the former can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: Now I'm trying to connect from my SSMS to a test database on another sql server (which I installed especially for the test), and got an error message to verify that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: Cannot connect to DESKTOP-BJ2KJOT\SQLEXPRESS.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1) Earlier today I did everything described here: https://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/   But still no remote connections allowed.

Comment: Is the windows service for that instance running?